# Negative resistance temperature coefficient of metals

Tags: temperature, electrical-resistance, electrical-engineering

How is it explainable that some metals have their electrical resistance increased while other metals act the other way?

When the temperature of a metal rises the molecules move faster and from my point of view then there are more free electrons which causes the electrical resistance to decrease. So this would be a positive temperature coefficient (PTC).

But how should, with more movement, the electrons bond better to the metal? This makes no sense out of my point of view.

Comment: Positive temperature coefficient is the opposite: higher resistance at higher temperature. Additionally, the electron flow is what really matters, not only the number of conduction electrons. Do you have examples of negative T coefficient metals?